# Using OpenAI Gym (Blackjack-v1)

Tags: python, openai-api, openai-gym

I am trying to implement a solution using the SARSA (State-Action-Reward-State-Action) algorithm for the Blackjack-v1 environment.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import gym

# SARSA parameters
alpha = 0.1
gamma = 0.99
epsilon = 0.1

# Function to discretize state space
def discretize_state(state):
    if isinstance(state, tuple):
        # If the state is a tuple, assume it has three elements
        player_sum, dealer_card, usable_ace = state
    else:
        # If the state is not a tuple, assume it has two elements and no usable_ace
        player_sum, dealer_card = state
        usable_ace = False

    player_sum = min(21, player_sum // 10)
    dealer_card = min(10, dealer_card - 1)
    return (player_sum, dealer_card, int(usable_ace))

# Function to choose an action using epsilon-greedy policy
def choose_action(Q, state):
    if np.random.uniform(0, 1) < epsilon:
        return np.random.choice([0, 1])  # 0 for stick, 1 for hit
    else:
        return np.argmax(Q[state])

# Function to update Q-values using SARSA
def update_Q(Q, state, action, reward, next_state, next_action):
    Q[state][action] += alpha * (reward + gamma * Q[next_state][next_action] - Q[state][action])

# Function to train the agent using SARSA
def train_agent(env, num_episodes):
    Q = np.zeros((10, 10, 2, 2))  # State space discretization

    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        state = discretize_state(env.reset())
        action = choose_action(Q, state)
        done = False

        while not done:
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            next_state = discretize_state(next_state)
            next_action = choose_action(Q, next_state)
            update_Q(Q, state, action, reward, next_state, next_action)
            state, action = next_state, next_action

    return Q

# Function to evaluate the trained agent
def evaluate_agent(Q, env, num_episodes):
    total_reward = 0
    for _ in range(num_episodes):
        state = discretize_state(env.reset())
        action = choose_action(Q, state)
        done = False

        while not done:
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            next_state = discretize_state(next_state)
            next_action = choose_action(Q, next_state)
            total_reward += reward
            state, action = next_state, next_action

    return total_reward / num_episodes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create Blackjack environment
    env = gym.make('Blackjack-v1')

    # Train the agent
    num_episodes = 100000
    Q_values = train_agent(env, num_episodes)

    # Evaluate the trained agent
    num_eval_episodes = 1000
    avg_reward = evaluate_agent(Q_values, env, num_eval_episodes)
    print(f"Average reward over {num_eval_episodes} episodes: {avg_reward}")
```

The `choose_action` function follows an epsilon-greedy policy, and the `update_Q` function updates the Q-values using the SARSA update rule.

And this is the error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40536\2433186481.py in <module>
     73     # Train the agent
     74     num_episodes = 100000
---> 75     Q_values = train_agent(env, num_episodes)
     76 
     77     # Evaluate the trained agent

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40536\2433186481.py in train_agent(env, num_episodes)
     37 
     38     for episode in range(num_episodes):
---> 39         state = discretize_state(env.reset())
     40         action = choose_action(Q, state)
     41         done = False

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40536\2433186481.py in discretize_state(state)
     11     if isinstance(state, tuple):
     12         # If the state is a tuple, assume it has three elements
---> 13         player_sum, dealer_card, usable_ace = state
     14     else:
     15         # If the state is not a tuple, assume it has two elements and no usable_ace

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I am a beginner at this and am unsure why I am getting the errors I am getting. Some help would be appreciated.

Have I made some errors in handling the different types of state representations returned by the Blackjack-v1 environment?

Comment: You are initializing `state` from `env.reset()`.  Evidently, `env.reset()` is only returning two values.  You'll need to check into `gym.make` to figure out why that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the observation space in BlackJack-v1 sometimes returns something like this:

```
((19, 7, 0), {})
```

I think that's why you got the error. I deal with this problem by the following code and it works fine.

```
if {} in observation:
    target, _ = observation
else:
    target = observation
score, dealer_score, usable_ace = target
```

In your case it should be:

```
if {} in state:
    target, _ = state
else:
    target = state
player_sum, dealer_card, usable_ace = target
```

You can try it and tell me whether it works.